# Do we need the extra column in the augmented matrix of a LP?

Tags: linear-programming

Consider the following linear program:

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{maximize} & x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \\
\text{subject to} & 60x_1 + 20x_2 +50x_3 \leq 1 \\
& 20x_1 + 50x_2 + 10x_3 \leq 1 \\
\text{and} & x_1, x_2, x_3 \geq 0
\end{array}
$$

It has the following augmented matrix form:

$$
\left[\begin{array}{cccccc|c}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & s_1 & s_2 & z \\ \hline
60 & 20 & 50 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
20 & 50 & 10 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
-1 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$

When solved, the matrix becomes:

$$
\left[\begin{array}{cccccc|c}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & s_1 & s_2 & z \\ \hline
\frac{26}{23} & 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{46} & \frac{-1}{115} & 0 & \frac{3}{230} \\
\frac{4}{23} & 1 & 0 & \frac{-1}{230} & \frac{1}{46} & 0 & \frac{2}{115} \\ \hline
\frac{7}{23} & 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{115} & \frac{3}{230} & 1 & \frac{7}{230}
\end{array}\right]
$$

As you can see, the $z$ column doesn't change. In practice I've seen that this is always the case. So, is there any need to keep the column $z$ around beside pedantic reasons?

I know that the solution is $\{ x_1 = 0, x_2 = \frac{2}{115}, x_3 = \frac{3}{230}, s_1 = 0, s_2 = 0, z = \frac{7}{230} \}$ which is why the equation $\frac{7}{23}x_1 + 0x_2 + 0x_3 + \frac{2}{115}s_1 + \frac{3}{230}s_2 + z = \frac{7}{230}$ holds true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [indeed alright](http://math.uww.edu/~mcfarlat/pcolumn.htm) to omit the $z$ column from the simplex tableau:

> However, during the row operations of the SIMPLEX METHOD, this **z**-COLUMN never changes, and therefore Prof McFarland chooses to omit it to save time and space, and to simplify the appearance of tableaus. Any student may either keep or omit this **z**-COLUMN: the row operations will be unaffected whichever you choose.

However, there's a caveat:

> The omission of a **z**-COLUMN has one cost: we must remember that in all simplex tableaus, the value of **z** is found in the lower right corner.